# Authenticate requests from landingpage to API passing through proxy

Tags: authentication, proxy, api

Imagine the scenario where you have a client who wants you to implement calls to an external API on a landingpage that you've setup for them. The external API works based on a contract and API keys which are obtained through that contract; hence you must not expose the API keys in `fetch()` calls from your frontend.

You thus now have the mandate to implement a Docker instance which acts as an intermediary server, connecting your LP's `fetch()` calls to the external API, such that, with every request, you have the following traffic:

`client --> Docker container --> API --> Docker container --> client`

To still keep security tight, I now wonder about the best approach to authenticate requests incoming from the client to the Docker container. Authorization is implemented via CSRF-tokens that are delivered to the client upon page load; post successful initial authentication.

Given that the landingpages have no login system and we cannot rely on not-HTTP / third-party cookies, I thought of only allowing requests to come in to the Docker container which originate from the domain of the deployed landingpage; but I don't know A) if this is possible (I thought of the `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin` config on the Docker container?), and B) if this is secure? I particularly wonder about B) because it is pretty easy to fake things like a referrer header, so I wonder if domain names from which a request originates may be faked in an easy way too?

If I also understood things correctly, the rule provided via the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is only enforced in browsers, and for example simple HTTP clients can circumvent / disregard it; correct?

I also thougt of basic authentication, but I'd prefer some kind of authentication that does not expose anything within the client code, as I would need to provide the authentication token to js in that case.

Given that the Docker container executes an apache server, I'm currently doing [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html), to restrict the access to the API according to the forbidden HOST header of the requesting client (by setting it to the domain of the LP which should be enabled to use the API). I know this is rather access restriction vs authentication; but I figure its the best solution for this landingpage-scenario?

Comment: what do you mean that "the Docker container runs on apache"? Maybe that the docker container executes an apache server?

Comment: Also, you say "post successful initial authentication" and then that "the landingpages have no login system".  If the landing page does not have any login system, how and when does the initial authentication take place?

Comment: Yes the docker container executes an apache server. As for the second question, that’s pretty much my question. Ie if it makes sense to restrict access to the application via the forbidden HOST header, by setting  sth like Require host <landingpage domain>. Because I cannot think of any authentication that would make sense here. And the host header would also block HTTP clients, hence it’s what I’m currently doing to avoid that whoever else may use the API. Just wonder if that’s secure, or if you can circumvent the host header?

Comment: And then, if that HOST check is passed, I verify the CSRF token for authorization. That’s what I meant by „post successful authentication“.